# Storing a UITextView into Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitextview, textfield

I have an application in which adds the text inside a UITextView into Core Data. But the Core data entry is a "string", so it only saves the first line of the UITextView into the core database.

How can I fix that? I would like to save into the core database all of the text which is in the UITextView.

Unfortunately the CoreRecipes sample project from Apple doesn't work anymore

Comment: Why do you think it's only got the first line? Are there line breaks?

Comment: Please show some code. Include that part of code where you check the content of the core data NSStrng. There should be everything in but your way of displaying it may stop following the first line. Be aware that UILabel have a numberOfLines (or so) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It saves all text - you must be wrong . if you look at it the DB  symbols / line breaks are a '\n'